# Table row background color skips rows

Tags: php

I have a PHP code, with JSON query loading records on a table, looping until all MySQL query results are read.

I'm trying to add table row background color. But it always only affects every other row.

I'm fairly new to PHP and Java. I only learn through trying and researching in the net and have not had any formal Java and PHP training.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Message Type</th>
        <th>Crime Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date/Time Reported</th>
        <th>Date/Time Committed</th>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
        <th>--</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<?php
$query = "SELECT reports.id, types.`name`, classifications.`name` as class, reports.description,
concat(DATE_FORMAT(reports.committed_at,'%b %e, %Y'), ' at ', TIME_FORMAT(reports.committed_at,'%l:%i:%p')) as committed_at,
concat(DATE_FORMAT(reports.created_at,'%b %e, %Y'), ' at ', TIME_FORMAT(reports.created_at,'%l:%i:%p')) as created_at,
reports.casestat, users.`name` as sender, concat(status.id, ' - ', status.status) as status FROM reports
INNER JOIN types ON reports.type_id = types.id
INNER JOIN classifications ON reports.classification_id = classifications.id
INNER JOIN users ON reports.created_by = users.id
INNER JOIN status ON reports.casestat = status.id"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
          switch($row['casestat']){

              case 0: $rwcol="#ff3c3c"; break; 
              case 1: $rwcol="#ffb93c"; break;
              case 2:$rwcol="#ffff3c"; break;
              case 3: $rwcol="#00bc00"; break;
              case 4: $rwcol="#5a5aff"; break;
               }                  
      echo "<tr bgcolor=$rwcol>";
      echo "<td id='code'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['class'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['created_at'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['committed_at'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['sender'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><a onclick='updateStat(this.id)' id='".$row['id']."' href='#' ><abbr title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></abbr>Update Status</a> </tr>";}
?>

</tbody>
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image: screen]

Comment: I think fault in this row : echo "<tr bgcolor='".$rwcol."'>";

Comment: Yes @GovindSamrow, the quotes were part of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bgcolor attribute is overwritten by your .table-striped class specified in your  tag.

[.table-striped](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-striped)

Comment: Thanks @wonyeouuu my bad, I forgot about it.